# How to prevent empty attachments from uploading on update action in Rails 7.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm rebuilding a much-outdated Rails app to skip several version migrations to the latest, 7.1. The relevant model has the following attribute: `has_many_attached :content_files`. When a record is updated using a a form, `content_files` are purged if no new `content_files` have been uploaded by the user.

In the logs, I see that `content_files` are passed as an empty array.

```
Started PATCH "/archive_items/75" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-01-16 10:33:53 -0800
10:33:53 web.1  | Processing by ArchiveItemsController#update as TURBO_STREAM
10:33:53 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "archive_item"=>{ "content_files"=>[""]}
```

Later in the logs I see:

```
10:59:04 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3  [["record_id", 75], ["record_type", "ArchiveItem"], ["name", "content_files"]]
10:59:04 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/archive_items_controller.rb:174:in `update'
10:59:04 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = $1  [["id", 401]]
10:59:04 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/archive_items_controller.rb:174:in `update'
```

In the initial build of this app, running on 6.0, the `content_files` params doesn't show up at all if no new files have been uploaded by the user. In using the `.update` method in the console,  attachment deletion does not occur.

I want to understand why an empty gets passed when no new files are uploaded.

I have found a solution by updating the the `update` action in the controller to check if the `:content_files` is empty and removing it from the params list:

```
def update
    @archive_item = ArchiveItem.find(params[:id])

    # create new params hash to remove empty content_files and medium_photos
    update_params = archive_item_params

    # check if content_files is empty and remove it from update_params if it is
    if archive_item_params[:content_files] == [""]
      update_params.delete(:content_files)
    end
    

    @archive_item.update(update_params)


    flash.alert = "An item has been updated."
    redirect_to archive_items_path
  end

  def destroy
    @archive_item = ArchiveItem.find(params[:id])
    @archive_item.destroy

    redirect_to archive_items_path
  end

  private

  def archive_item_params
    params.require(:archive_item).permit(:poster_image, :title, :medium, :year, :credit, :location, :tag_list, :location_list, :person_list, :comm_group_list, :collection_list, :date_is_approx, :content_notes, :medium_notes, :medium_photo, :search_tags, :search_locations, :search_people, :search_comm_groups, :search_collections, :created_by, :updated_by, :updated_at, content_files: [], :medium_photos => [])
  end
```

However, I want understand why an empty param gets passed as empty if no new files are uploaded.

Per request here's the relevant form field:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <% if @archive_item.content_files.attached? %>
      <div class="form-set">
        <label>Content Preview</label>
          <% @archive_item.content_files.each do |file| %>
            <% if @archive_item.medium == "photo" %>
              <% if file.content_type == "image/jpeg" || file.content_type == "image/png" %>
                <%= image_tag file.variant(resize_to_limit: [600, nil]), class: "admin-form-image" %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'View file', file, target: "_blank", class: "download-link" %>
              <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <div class="admin-form-filename">File: <%= file.filename %></div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-set">
      <%= form.label :content_files, "Content File" %>
      <%= form.file_field :content_files, direct_upload: true, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your form - looks like it sends empty string, when nothing is entered in the field

Comment: Post is updated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```rb
# Evaluates the opposite of if statement
unless params[:content_files].empty?
  # Will includes the :content_files if there is an attached file
  @archive_item.update(update_params)
else
  # Will excludes the :content_files from the params if it comes empty
  @archive_item.update(update_params.except(:content_files))
end
```

or

```rb
# this is a ternary evaluation, if the param is empty, then exclude it from the params list
params[:content_files].empty? ? @archive_item.update(update_params.except(:content_files)) : @archive_item.update(update_params)
```

By doing this, you could remove the next code:

```rb
# create new params hash to remove empty content_files and medium_photos
update_params = archive_item_params

# check if content_files is empty and remove it from update_params if it is
if archive_item_params[:content_files] == [""]
  update_params.delete(:content_files)
end

@archive_item.update(update_params)
```

Also you can add a model validation:

```rb
has_many_attached :content_files
validate validate_attached_presence

private

def validate_attached_presence
  errors.add(:content_files, "can't be blank") unless content_files.attached?
end
```